# Custom Connector function doesn't like parameters, only optional parameters

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m, power-platform

I'm in the process of creating my own Custom Connector, using the Power Query SDK in VS Code.

I've got everything working with hard-coded values, and now want to have these constants as parameters of my functions.

For this, I've created the following setup in my `MyConnector.pq` file:

```
[DataSource.Kind="MyConnector"]
shared MyConnector.Query = (message as text) =>
    let
        response = QueryImpl(message)
    in
        response;
```

This is invoked in the `MyConnector.query.pq` file to validate.

```
let
    result = MyConnector.Query("Hi")
in 
   result
```

When doing this, I get the following error:

> The name 'MyConnector.Query' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Changing the `message` parameter to an optional parameter makes the code run fine.

```
[DataSource.Kind="MyConnector"]
shared MyConnector.Query = (optional message as text) =>
    let
        response = QueryImpl(message)
    in
        response;
```

There's probably something obvious I'm missing, but I can't figure out what. All appears to be 'just like in the docs'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe try:

```
[DataSource.Kind="MyConnector"]
shared MyConnector.Content = Value.ReplaceType(QueryImpl, type function (message as text) as any);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had indeed tried this but it yielded the same error. I'm actually using `shared MyConnector.Query = Value.ReplaceType(QueryImpl, QueryType);` in my code, but simplified it to make it more readable in the post.